# How to update the property of parent component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have 2 livewire components:

**MyForm Component**

```
class MyForm extends Component
{
    public $selectedA = [];
    public $selectedB = [];
}

<livewire:checkboxs title="A" :items="$itemsA" wire:model="selectedA" />
<livewire:checkboxs title="B" :items="$itemsB" wire:model="selectedB" />
```

**Checkboxs Component**

```
class Checkboxs extends Component
{
    public $title;
    public $items = [];
    public $value = [];
}

<div>
    <div>
        <div>{{ $this->title }}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @foreach($this->items as $item)
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" wire:model="value" value="{{ $item->id }}" @input="$emit('input', @json($this->value))">
            {{ $item->name }}
        </label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to update `$selectedA` and `$selectedB` on `MyForm` Component when there is any change on `Checkboxs` Component. How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to use livewire events: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#firing-events

Comment: Events would work as Kevin suggests, but this is one of the cases where it's better to just use plain blade components for the checkboxes instead of nested livewire components.